# Link within Label doesn't set focus on attributed input

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a One Pager website where I have a navigation menu. I'd want to have `radio` input associated to the clicked `a`, in order to apply some CSS to the active `radio`.

As you will see, the CSS is applied when I click on the `radio`, but not when I click on the link. I know I could do this using JavaScript, but I am trying to avoid growing my code base.

The second section of the snippet is what I'd want to achieve, but with an `a` tag in the `label`. The `radio` will be hidden, so clicking on the `radio` isn't an acceptable answer. How can I make the `a` tag *and* the `input` tag activate?

```css
    input[type=radio]:checked + label {
        color:red;
        background-color:green;
    }
    .working {
        visibility: hidden;
        width:0;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Not working with a tag</h2>
            <div>
                <input id="a" type="radio" name="menu1" value="a"/>
                <label for="a"><a href="#">Input 1</a></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="b" type="radio" name="menu1" value="b"/>
                <label for="b"><a href="#">Input 2</a></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Expected result (without a, it doesn't work)</h2>
            <div>
                <input class="working" id="c" type="radio" name="menu2" value="a"/>
                <label for="c">Input 1</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="working" id="d" type="radio" name="menu2" value="b"/>
                <label for="d">Input 2</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right solution is here , try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name=title_format]').click(function()  {
        $('[name=doc-title]').val('Title changed to '+$(this).val());
    });
});
</script>

<style>
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    color:red;
    background-color:green;
}
.working {
    width:0;
}
</style>

<div>
    <h2>Not working with a tag</h2>
    <div>
        <a href="#">
        <input type="radio" name="title_format" class="title-format" id="title-format-0" value="0" checked="checked">               <label for="title-format-0">Input 1</label>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
         <a href="#">
        <input type="radio" name="title_format" class="title-format" id="title-format-1" value="1"> 
        <label for="title-format-1">Input 2</label>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Expected result (without a, it doesn't work)</h2>
    <div>
        <input class="working" id="c" type="radio" name="menu2" value="a"/>
        <label for="c">Input 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="working" id="d" type="radio" name="menu2" value="b"/>
        <label for="d">Input 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I upvoted before, because I thought it worked, but it doesn't work. It does change the style but the navigation for the `<a>` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of the label syntax: https://jsfiddle.net/93c3sscs/

If you're testing on IE11 or your customers use IE (not sure about Edge and other IE versions), you can't rely on labels to activate inputs. IE does not apply clickable functionality to `<label><input></label>`, and Microsoft put out 2 updates in the second half of 2015 that completely broke my app because of this by positioning the clickable area 5px *above* my widget sprites.